# Getting a MYSQL 1064 error when creating a function

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
DELIMITER $$

    CREATE FUNCTION nameOfFunct(intIn int)
    RETURN int
    BEGIN
        DECLARE intOut INT;
        SET intOut = SELECT count(*)
            FROM tableToTakeFrom
            WHERE columToCompareTo = intIn;

        RETURN intOut;
    END;
        $$

DELIMITER;
```

If I try to run this all I get is:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
>   'RETURN int
>       BEGIN
>           DECLARE intOut INT;
>           SET intOut = select count(' at line 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of changes to resolve the problem:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION nameOfFunct(intIn INT)
-- RETURN INT
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE intOut INT;
    /*SET intOut = SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM tableToTakeFrom
        WHERE columToCompareTo = intIn;*/
    SET intOut = (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM tableToTakeFrom
        WHERE columToCompareTo = intIn);
    RETURN intOut;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining the return type is done by the `RETURNS` keywrod, not the `RETURN` keyword:

```
CREATE FUNCTION nameOfFunct(intIn int)
RETURNS int
BEGIN
    DECLARE intOut INT;
    SET intOut = SELECT count(*) 
                 FROM   tableToTakeFrom
                 WHERE  columToCompareTo = intIn;
    RETURN intOut;
END;
```